# angular ng-repeat and images in a row

Tags: javascript, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my view model I have an array of exactly 4 icon names.

If I place the 4 images like so:

```
<img ng-src="{{'/Content/img/' + vm.indicator[0]}}" alt="" />
<img ng-src="{{'/Content/img/' + vm.indicator[1]}}" alt="" />
<img ng-src="{{'/Content/img/' + vm.indicator[2]}}" alt="" />
<img ng-src="{{'/Content/img/' + vm.indicator[3]}}" alt="" />
```

they appear nicely in a row as desired.

However, when I use

```
<div ng-repeat="indicator in vm.indicator track by $index">
    <img ng-src="{{'/Content/img/' + indicator}}" alt="" />
</div>
```

they appear below each other. (note: I need the "track by $index" bit because some icons have the same name).

I don't understand it. If I just place an empty div around the first code nothing changes. Why would the ng-repeat div change anything?
And how can I make the two code snippets behave the same?

This is not a huge problem in my case because I always have exactly 4 icon names in my array. But what if the array was of variable length?

Comment: One thing you could try is to render the URL directly: `<div ng-repeat="indicator in vm.indicator track by $index">{{ '/Content/img/' + indicator }}</div>` to rule out any issues with the variable / loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the ng-repeat in the img tag like so

```
<div >
    <img ng-repeat="indicator in vm.indicator track by $index" ng-src="{{'/Content/img/' + indicator}}" alt="" />
</div>
```

That way you dont make multiple divs

Comment: Ahh! Your comment clarified it for me. When using ng-repeat each image is placed in it's own div. That explains why they appear each on it's own line. Thanks. That explanation was what I was after. Your code suggestion almost fixes it, except that now there are no more spaces between the images, which is easy to fix of course.

Comment: @hholtij yea ng-repeat repeats the element wich it is in.