# How to create ng-repeat of images that appear in line with using a div for the ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I currently have many images in an ng-repeat. I want them to fill the page horizontally then go down however far (kinda like google images...they fill up the whole page).  Well, I need to have the ng-repeat on a parent div because of some ng-class stuff that I'm doing based on certain image criteria and stacking things and so forth.  The code I originally had (when I had the ng-repeat on the image) worked well, but now I need the ng-repeat on the div, and it is repeating the div attribute making the images stack. I got that solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279197/angular-ng-repeat-and-images-in-a-row). Here is the previous code:

```
<img class="movImg" ng-src="{{movie.imgPath}}" ng-repeat="movie in movies"/>
```

Now I need to do something like this:

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    <div class="mainContent" Overflow:scroll style="">
       <img class="movImg" ng-src="{{movie.imgPath}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The repeat works, but I end up with a billion images in one column.  Does anyone know how I can have the ng-repeat on the div, but keep the layout as before (dynamic number of columns/with the images taking up the width on the page)?

Here is the CSS that I'm using

```
.mainContent {
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin-top:40px;
  overflow:scroll;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
.movImg {
  display:inline;
  margin:7.5px;
  width:150px;
}
```

Comment: I would put the repeat on the parent div, then use css to control how many images can fit into a row. It would only require one repeater.

Comment: So I am currently trying to put the ng-repeat on the parent div (as shown in the second block of code), but I can't figure out how to get the images in a row.

Comment: Hmm, are You using bootstrap? Maybe You should add some bootstrap class for div?

Comment: `display: inline;` on the `div`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that I needed to put a style of `display:inline` on the div of the ng-repeat. 
Thank you all for the help.